# Click a Link on Table row is working in IDE but not able to do it using Webdriver using same Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Working in IDE with below mentioned code:

selectFrame :-

```
    <td>3</td>

//table[@id='HSS']/thead/tr/th[2]
```

but same is not working with webdriver.

```
driver.switch_to_frame(3)
search_field=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='HSS']/thead/tr/th[2]").click()
```

HTML of element:

```
table id="HSS" class="menu_table"
<thead>
tr onclick="submitValue('HSS', 1);ems_create_node_menu_div();" style="cursor:pointer;"
class="menu_table_th" width="13%" colspan="1"
class="menu_table_th" width="36%" colspan="1">  HSS
```

Comment: Can you post the url to check it?